# Giving element focus doesnt seem to work when tab is in background

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, focus, blur

I am trying to scrape a webpage using javascript and firefox. On the page, the new content loads with ajax when the form inputs change. My script fills in the form input, removes focus from it, and detects the ajax content loading.

The problem is that it doesnt work if the browser tab does not have focus. So I have to have it running in the foreground all the time which is inconvenient.

here is the page
(it seems to have an onchange() event handler on the 'location' form input.) 
...

http://www.winkworth.co.uk/

And here is what I am running in the firefox console to test it
(when it works you will seee a message below the form: "Below are the properties we found")

If you run firebug in the same browser tab (as a panel at the bottom) this will work.
However if you detach the firebug panel (making it a seperate window), so that when it has focus, the browser window will not, then the ajax loader doesnt run.

```
//change the value and then remove focus
document.getElementById('location').value= "N1";
document.getElementById('location').focus();
document.getElementById('location').blur();
```

Comment: Have you tried post message? For communication between pages, it seems to be the most reliable means.

Comment: I hadnt heard of postMessage, so thanks for the suggestion. However as I understand it, I cant use it as I dont have access to the page I'm scraping so I cant add a "addEventListener('message', .." to it.